# Problem trying to run pyspark with Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, command-prompt

I need to run pyspark with Jupyter notebook. (I use Windows 10)

I tried this in Anaconda Prompt:

```
pip install spark
pip install pyspark
SET PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
SET PYSPARK_DRIVER_OPTS='notebook'
pyspark
```

And returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 247, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 134, in _jupyter_abspath
    'Jupyter command `{}` not found.'.format(jupyter_subcommand)
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\find_spark_home.py` not found.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are not working in Windows. There is a very good guide [here](https://medium.com/@am.benatmane/setting-up-a-spark-environment-with-jupyter-notebook-and-apache-zeppelin-on-ubuntu-e12116d6539e).  Assuming you have everything installed, you need to edit your `./bashrc` from your home directory using something like:

```
nano .bashrc
```

and adding the following:

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
```

then you need to apply the changes:

```
source .bashrc
```

and then when you run the command

```
pyspark
```

It should work

Comment: Try to define these variables (`PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON`, `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON`) in your [system](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). Or use a Linux VM or Image.